# Error comparing arrays in C#: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'sequenceEqual'

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I'm reading two Excel worksheets using C# & .NET 4.7.2:

```
var sheet1 = newWS.UsedRange.Value;
var sheet2 = oldWS.UsedRange.Value;
```

A watch on the sheet1 (or sheet2) shows an array as expected.  But when I try to compare them using:

```
if (sheet1.SequenceEqual(sheet2))
```

it fails with 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual'

I have declared:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and in fact I have got SequenceEqual to work using a trivial example in the same module:

```
            string[] array1 = { "dot", "net", "deves" };
            string[] array3 = { "dot", "net", "deves" };
            bool b = array1.SequenceEqual(array3);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
```

So what am I missing here?  Does it not like the arrays being variant?  Is System.Array a particular type of array that doesn't have sequenceEqual implemented?  It's not implemented in this version of .NET?  I have the case wrong???  Or more likely something else entirely?

Any hints appreciated.

(Of course the bigger question is the best way to compare the two arrays, sheet1 & sheet2 -- It looks like SequenceEqual should do what I need, but maybe there's a better way?)

Comment: Will casting it to an appropriate .net type and doing `SequenceEquals` help ? What type is `sheet1`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I think it's boxed into an `object`, since the VBA type is [variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)

Answer (score 3):

`SequenceEqual` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. `System.Array` does not implement the typed `IEnumerable<T>`, only the untyped `IEnumerable`. That why your compiler complains.

It's easy to compare two arrays of strings. It is known how to compare two string, the rest of the job can be a nice loop. But how should this method even start to compare two things of *untyped* type. Two objects of unknown structure? When would two objects even be equal to each other?

If you know what your arrays contain, you can transform it to two *typed* arrays that contain the values you want to compare and then you can use the method `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: Had a feeling that it was something like that.  At least I know that what I'm hitting my head against is a brick-wall, and that I should stop and find something softer.  Maybe a Lego wall.